# Chromium not inferring menuitem name from shadow DOM contents

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, web-component

[CodeSandbox demonstrating issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-elements-chromium-issue-gfjjm)

I'm building a menu using Custom Elements. It works fine for keyboard and mouse users, but I noticed an issue when testing with a screenreader: all of my `menuitems` have no labels. You can see this in the Accessibility Inspector:

[image]

Each menuitem is essentially a custom element with a <slot> and some styling—that's it. When not using web components, if one does this:

```html
<button role="menuitem">Foo</button>
```

Then the Chrome accessibility inspector will show "menuitem: 'Foo'" because **it infers the name from the contents**. With web components, this isn't the case—Chrome is showing *no name*. Here's a side-by-side comparison when I use the accessibility inspector inside the CodeSandbox I shared above.

[image]

Firefox and Safari both successfully infer the name of these menuitems. Chromium-based browsers are not. Is this a Chrome bug? Are the other browsers just working by coincidence? Is there anything I can do here? I'm really trying to avoid weird stuff where I pull the slot's `innerText` and add it to an `aria-label` or something.

Comment: Noteworthy addendum: if I change the component's `role` from `menuitem` to `button`, then Chrome _does_ infer the name correctly. Truly strange.

Comment: Report it as an issue: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues